# prevent leading zeros being stripped when outputting to csv from sql server

Tags: sql

Hi i have a SQL script which outputs some columns of data one of which is a phone number, into a csv  file. The script all works fine however the leading zero is stripped from the  phone number. Now i know all about why leading zeros are stripped from phone numbers when opening a csv in excel that contains them.

The bit im struggling with is the SQL script to surround the phone  number in double quotes so that its interpreted as text when opened. see my sql below:

```
SET @query ='
SELECT
    ''MobilePhoneNumber'' AS MobilePhoneNumber
    ,''RequestNumber'' AS RequestNumber
    ,''RequestDate'' AS RequestDate
    ,''RequestType'' AS RequestType
    ,''Status'' AS Status
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    [MobilePhoneNumber] --I Want to get this column in the csv as EG "01234123456"
    ,[RequestNumber]
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[RequestDate],120)
    ,[RequestType]
    ,[Status]
FROM [Mobiles].[dbo].[Requests]
WHERE [RequestType] = ''Cease''
    AND DATEDIFF(mm,Requestdate , GETDATE())=1;'
```

Comment: Can you not convert the MobilePhoneNumber to a VARCHAR like you have for RequestDate or would this still remove the zero?

Comment: I think if you add single quote'  infront of number in csv output, excel will display it properly

Comment: i used CHAR(96) + [MobilePhoneNumber]  and it worked a treat

Comment: Your title is misleading. It appears the leading zeros are **not stripped when outputting** to the CSV file, it is Excel that **removes them when opening** the CSV.

Comment: Btw, you can post your final solution as an answer an 'accept' that one. So others can see this question has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
'...
SELECT 
CHAR(34) + [MobilePhoneNumber] + CHAR(34)
...'
```

Or

```
'...
SELECT 
''"'' + [MobilePhoneNumber] + ''"''
...'
```

Comment: well it did surround the phone number as expected but excel ignored it and stripped off the zeros, however i just did this: CHAR(96) + [MobilePhoneNumber] and it worked and it opened up as so also :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion from @KekuSemau Here is my solution in the end for the benefit of others:

```
SET @query ='
SELECT
    ''MobilePhoneNumber'' AS MobilePhoneNumber
    ,''RequestNumber'' AS RequestNumber
    ,''RequestDate'' AS RequestDate
    ,''RequestType'' AS RequestType
    ,''Status'' AS Status
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CHAR(39) +[MobilePhoneNumber] -- < I simply added the CHAR(39)
    ,[RequestNumber]
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[RequestDate],120)
    ,[RequestType]
    ,[Status]
FROM [Mobiles].[dbo].[Requests]
WHERE [RequestType] = ''Cease''
    AND DATEDIFF(mm,Requestdate , GETDATE())=1;'
```